# How to create validator for edit page

Tags: java, sql, jsf, jsf-2

I have an unusual problem which I don't know how to solve.

I have a edit page which is used to edit data from database table. When the user opens the page he sees input value for example `90`. Using the below Java code the input field is checked for duplication into the DB table. And now here is the problem: When the user opens the edit page and clicks the submit button he gets every time the message `90 is already in use!`. I need to find a solution how to pass the original value to the validator and also to check the value into the DB table. Maybe this sql query is not correct.

```
// Validate Datacenter ID

    public void validateDatacenterID(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException, SQLException
    {

        Long l;
        String s = value.toString().trim();

        if (s.length() > 18)
        {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  Value is too long! (18 digits max)", null));
        }

        try
        {
            l = Long.parseLong(s);
            if (l > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  '" + l + "' is too large!", null));
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { l = null; }


        if (l != null)
        {

            if (ds == null) throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");

            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs;
            int cnt = 0;
            try
            {
                conn = ds.getConnection();
                ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT count(1) from COMPONENTSTATS where COMPONENTSTATSID = ?");
                ps.setLong(1, l);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()) cnt = rs.getInt(1);

                if (cnt > 0)
                {
                    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  '" + l + "' is already in use!", null));
                }

            }
            catch(SQLException x)
            {
                throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  SQL error!", null));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ps != null) ps.close();
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        s.isEmpty() ? "  This field cannot be empty!" : "  '" + s + "' is not a number!", null));
        }

    }
```

How I can solve this problem.

Comment: The problem could only be your DB lookup logic: The variable is initialized inline in your method and the exception will only occur when `(cnt > 0)`.You might want to check what exactly `rs.getInt(1)` is returning. On a side note, opening a connection, and preparing a statement inside a converter is *very* inefficient and a waste of the `PreparedStatement`(it's supposed to be precompiled once and reused)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of giving "COUNT(1)" try giving "COUNT(*)" or "count(columnName)".

Comment: Please refer to [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/182862). Since you lack enough rep to add comments, then add a complete answer or don't answering.